# The sort order for files and folders whose names contain numerals is incorrect in sharepoint

Tags: sorting

The sort order for files and folders whose names contain numerals is incorrect, such as my actually sort result is as following:

Ie4_01
Ie4_128
Ie401sp2
Ie5
Ie501sp2
Ie6

But my expected result is:

Ie4_01
Ie4_128
Ie5
Ie6
Ie401sp2
Ie501sp2

The issue is just as here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/76b6f4d9-db1e-40a9-8407-13b8bcf6c1c3/ stated.

How can I resolve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

During a sort, the values are compared character by character.

This is normal behavior. `4 < 5 < 6`, so that's how they should be sorted.

`A < B < C`, but you don't expect `AZ` to come after `BA`, because `A < B`

Comment: If you sort these folders in Windows explorer, you will find the result is different

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a alphanumeric sorting using an IComparer interface

http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting

Comment: Is there any way that don't need programing? Thanks